# Firebase TIMESTAMP to date and Time

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using firebase for my chat application. In chat object I am adding time stamp using `Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` method.

I need to show the message received time in my chat application using this Time stamp .

if it's current time i need to show the time only.It's have days difference i need to show the date and time or only date.

I used the following code for convert the Firebase time stamp but i not getting the actual time.

```
var timestamp = '1452488445471';
var myDate = new Date(timestamp*1000);
var formatedTime=myDate.toJSON();
```

Please suggest the solution for this issue

Comment: I think you don't have to multiply timestamp with 1000

Comment: Then How can i convert?

Comment: var myDate = new Date(timestamp); // thats it

Comment: what format you want output to be ?

Comment: I want to show only time and date separate

Comment: @Bek javascript's new Date() is converting from milliseconds, so you need that *1000 because Firebase returns something like this for a timestamp: { "seconds": 1537022235, "nanoseconds": 353000000 }
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

Answer (score 56):

A `Timestamp` is an object:

```js
timestamp = {
  nanoseconds: 0,
  seconds: 1562524200
}

console.log(new Date(timestamp.seconds*1000))
```

Comment: I think this is what the user us asking

Comment: Totally works and returns date in - Day (alphabetic ) month (alphabetic ) date (numerical) year (numerical)  time (hh:mm) and Time zone (GMT+ ..). Thanks

Comment: Why do you multiply seconds * 1000? Thank you

Comment: `new Date(milliseconds)` the function accepts ms, to convert seconds to ms we multiply by 1000 
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_dates.asp#:~:text=minutes%2C%20seconds%2C%20milliseconds)-,new%20Date(milliseconds),-new%20Date(date

Answer (score 36):

[Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/servervalue/timestamp.html) is not actual timestamp it is constant that will be replaced with actual value in server if you have it set into some variable.

```
mySessionRef.update({ startedAt: Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP });
mySessionRef.on('value', function(snapshot){ console.log(snapshot.val()) })
//{startedAt: 1452508763895}
```

if you want to get server time then you can use following code

```
  fb.ref("/.info/serverTimeOffset").on('value', function(offset) {
    var offsetVal = offset.val() || 0;
    var serverTime = Date.now() + offsetVal;
  });
```

Comment: If you do `console.log(new Date(snapshot.val()))`, you'll see the date as a string. `var date = new Date(snapshot.val())` will give you the date in an object that you can call useful functions on: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Answer (score 31):

inside Firebase Functions transform the timestamp like so:

```
timestampObj.toDate()
timestampObj.toMillis().toString()
```

documentation here https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp

Answer (score 23):

In fact, it only work to me when used

```
firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
```

With one 'database' more on namespace.

Comment: but it use the format like 1486106680368 how can i convert it into date and time

Comment: @AyazAhmadTarar if you are using angular, can simply use their built in pipes such as 'Date', or use angular2-moment to easily convert the timestamp

Comment: @WilliamWu but it will use the CLIENT timestamp.. not? The firebase ServerValue.TIMESTAMP ensure that it's the "real" time from server.

Answer (score 23):

For those looking for the Firebase [Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/) equivalent. It's

```
firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
```

e.g.

```
firebase.firestore().collection("cities").add({
    createdAt: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
    name: "Tokyo",
    country: "Japan"
})
.then(function(docRef) {
    console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
})
.catch(function(error) {
    console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
});
```

[Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.FieldValue)

Comment: I am trying to use this solution however  I get the following error - ReferenceError: firebase is not defined.  I am using js

Comment: Rahul, it sounds like you don't have the firebase library installed or loaded. Are you using the web version or the Node JS version? https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart

Comment: I found that by adding a new field name 'createdAt' to a 'timestamp' value, it automatically creates a timestamp for all documents

Answer (score 9):

For Firestore that is the new generation of database from Google, following code will simply help you through this problem.

```
var admin    = require("firebase-admin");

var serviceAccount = require("../admin-sdk.json"); // auto-generated file from Google firebase.

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount)
});
var db = admin.firestore();

console.log(admin.firestore.Timestamp.now().toDate());
```

Answer (score 9):

I know the firebase give the timestamp in `{seconds: '', and nanoseconds: ''}`
for converting into date u have to only do:

- take a firebase time in one var ex:- const date

and then `date.toDate()` => It returns the date.

Answer (score 8):

#### Solution for newer versions of Firebase (after Jan 2016)

The proper way to attach a timestamp to a database update is to attach a placeholder value in your request. In the example below Firebase will replace the `createdAt` property with a timestamp:

```
firebaseRef = firebase.database().ref();
firebaseRef.set({
  foo: "bar", 
  createdAt: firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
});
```

According to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/ServerValue), the value `firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` is: "A placeholder value for auto-populating the current timestamp (time since the Unix epoch, in milliseconds) by the Firebase Database servers."

Answer (score 6):

Here is a safe method to convert a value from firebase Timestamp type to JS Date
in case the value is not Timestamp the method returns it as it is

Works for Angular 7/8/9

```
import firebase from 'firebase';
import Timestamp = firebase.firestore.Timestamp;

export function convertTimestampToDate(timestamp: Timestamp | any): Date | any {
  return timestamp instanceof Timestamp
    ? new Timestamp(timestamp.seconds, timestamp.nanoseconds).toDate()
    : timestamp;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this one,

```
var timestamp = firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
var timestamp2 = new Date(timestamp.toDate()).toUTCString()
```

Answer (score 5):

Working with Firebase Firestone 18.0.1
(com.google.firebase.Timestamp)

```
val timestamp = (document.data["timestamp"] as Timestamp).toDate()
```

Answer (score 4):

It is simple. Use that function to get server timestamp as milliseconds **one time only**:

```
var getServerTime = function( cb ) {
    this.db.ref( '.info/serverTimeOffset' ).once( 'value', function( snap ) {
      var offset = snap.val();

      // Get server time by milliseconds
      cb( new Date().getTime() + offset );
    });
};
```

Now you can use it anywhere like that:

```
getServerTime( function( now ) {
    console.log( now );
});
```

---

### Why use this way?

According to latest Firebase documentation, you should convert your Firebase timestamp into milliseconds. So you can use `estimatedServerTimeMs` variable below:

```
var offsetRef = firebase.database().ref(".info/serverTimeOffset");
offsetRef.on("value", function(snap) {
  var offset = snap.val();
  var estimatedServerTimeMs = new Date().getTime() + offset;
});
```

> While firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP is much more accurate,
>   and preferable for most read/write operations, it can occasionally be
>   useful to estimate the client's clock skew with respect to the
>   Firebase Realtime Database's servers. You can attach a callback to the
>   location /.info/serverTimeOffset to obtain the value, in milliseconds,
>   that Firebase Realtime Database clients add to the local reported time
>   (epoch time in milliseconds) to estimate the server time. Note that
>   this offset's accuracy can be affected by networking latency, and so
>   is useful primarily for discovering large (> 1 second) discrepancies
>   in clock time.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/offline-capabilities

Answer (score 2):

`new Date(timestamp.toDate()).toUTCString()`

Comment: add explanation

Answer (score 2):

```
    import firebaseAPP from 'firebase/app';


    public Date2firestoreTime(fromDate: Date) {
       return firebaseAPP.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(fromDate).toMillis()
    }
    public firestoreTime2Date(millisecDate: number) {
       return firebaseAPP.firestore.Timestamp.fromMillis(millisecDate).toDate()
    }


    //usage:
    let FSdatenow = this.Date2firestoreTime(new Date())
    console.log('now to firestore TimeStamp', FSdatenow)
    let JSdatenow = this.firestoreTime2Date(FSdatenow)
    console.log('firestore TimeStamp to Date Obj', JSdatenow)
```

Comment: see usage section:-)

Answer (score 1):

```js
var date = new Date((1578316263249));//data[k].timestamp
console.log(date);
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterating through this is the precise code that worked for me.

```
querySnapshot.docs.forEach((e) => {
   var readableDate = e.data().date.toDate();
   console.log(readableDate);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For me it works when the timeStamp is an integer rather than a string:

```
var timestamp = '1452488445471';
var myDate = new Date(parseInt(timestamp));
myDate.toDateString()
```

Answer (score 0):

I converted to this format

```
let timestamp = '1452488445471';
let newDate = new Date(timestamp * 1000)
let Hours = newDate.getHours()
let Minutes = newDate.getMinutes()
const HourComplete = Hours + ':' + Minutes
let formatedTime = HourComplete
console.log(formatedTime)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let jsDate = new Date(date.seconds * 1000 + date.nanoseconds / 1000000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have to specify the type to use `.toDate()` like this;

```
import { Timestamp } from "firebase/firestore";
...
(dateVariable as unknown as Timestamp).toDate()
```

This was `.toDate()` works as intended.

Answer (score -1):

First Of All `Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` is not working anymore for me.

So for adding timestamp you have to use `Firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP`

And the timestamp is in long millisecond format.To convert millisecond to simple dateformat .

Ex- dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss

You can use the following code in java:

To get the timestamp value in string from the firebase database

```
String x = dataSnapshot.getValue (String.class);
```

The data is in string now. You can convert the `string` to `long`

```
long milliSeconds= Long.parseLong(x);
```

Then create SimpleDateFormat

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss");
```

Now convert your millisecond timestamp to ur sdf format

```
String dateAsString = sdf.format (milliSeconds);
```

After that you can parse it to ur `Date` variable

```
 date = sdf.parse (dateAsString);
```

Comment: the question is for js not java

Answer (score -1):

This code is work for me

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.5.1/firebase.js"></script>
<script>
var config = {
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "",
    databaseURL: "",
    projectId: "",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: ""
};

firebase.initializeApp(config);
var reff = firebase.database().ref('message');
reff.on('value',haveData, haveerr);
function haveData(datahave){
    var existval= datahave.val();
    var chabi=Object.keys(existval);
    for(var d2=0;d2< chabi.length;d2++){
        var r=chabi[d2];
        var exitval=existval[r].Message;
        var exitval1=existval[r].Name;
        var exit=existval[r].Email;
        var exitval2=existval[r].Subject;
        var timestamp=existval[r].timestamp;
        var sdate=new Date(timestamp);
        var Year=sdate.getFullYear();
        var month=sdate.getMonth()+1;
        var day=sdate.getDate();
        var hh=sdate.getHours();
        var mm=sdate.getMinutes();
        var ss=sdate.getSeconds();
    }
}

function haveerr(e){
     console.log(e);
}
</script>
```

[image: firebase database]

Answer (score -12):

`Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` is the same as `new Date().getTime()`.

Convert it:

```
var timestamp = '1452488445471';
var myDate = new Date(timestamp).getTime();
```

Comment: Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP is a Firebase constant value not a UNIX timestamp.

Comment: the return value after setting it in the database is a UNIX timestamp but the actual command is not, so while yes at some point they resolve to the same thing and can be thusly converted, one must be careful to not try an duse the Firebase timestamp value the same way they would the getTime function in an operation.