# To get negativeTimestamp, why does it throw NaN error when 0 minus a positive number?

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

hero.ts

```
export class Hero {
  name: string;
  timestamp: number;
  negativeTimestamp: number;

  constructor() {
    this.name = '';
    this.timestamp = firebase.database['ServerValue']['TIMESTAMP'];
    this.negativeTimestamp = 0 - firebase.database['ServerValue']['TIMESTAMP'];
  }

}
```

It throws error when I create an object from this class using new Hero();
The error message is

> EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Firebase.push failed: first
>   argument contains NaN in property
>   'heroes.zeNtSMyJGvdZkMcxXsdfwSsbmSBrv2.negativeTimestamp'

`this.timestamp` works. It generated a timestamp value in Firebase database. That is correct. But how to get a negativeTimestamp?

My objective is to make timestamp from positive value to negative timestamp value. It's for using firebase descending ordering purpose.

Comment: You're trying to perform a client-side calculation with a server-side timestamp. I don't think that will work.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/34719492/3731501

Comment: What can I do to make it work on client-side?

Comment: After seeing estus posted link, I understand it now. I got a little hack to get this working with Angular2. Thanks.