# How to get current timestamp with Firebase react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

Alright I've followed this question verbatim [Firebase TIMESTAMP to date and Time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34718668/firebase-timestamp-to-date-and-time) and am posting to my Firebase database like this:

```
function storeUserInfo(username, industry, role, color) {
  if (username != null && industry != null && role != null && color != null) { //use for errors later
    let timestamp = firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp();

    let push = firebase.database().ref('users').push();
    push.set({
      name: username,
      industry: industry,
      role: role,
      color: color,
      date: new Date(timestamp.toDate()).toUTCString()
    });
  }
}
```

This gives me the error: `timestamp.toDate() is not a function`

Ive tried several other methods like `Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` but need to get the current formatted date for Firebase database. How can I do this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60516205/5449238

Comment: @anthonywillismuñoz The link seems to be for Firestore, while this question is about Realtime Database. While both databases are part of Firebase, they're completely separate and the APIs are quite different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of things going wrong here.  Firstly, you're trying to write to Realtime Database (via `firebase.database()`), but you're trying to use Firestore's timetamp with it.  Firestore and Realtime Database are different databases with different APIs.  A Firestore timestamp would not be helpful to you here.

If you want to get a date as reckoned by the client machine's clock, simply call `new Date()` with no arguments.

```
    push.set({
      name: username,
      industry: industry,
      role: role,
      color: color,
      date: new Date().toUTCString()
    });
```

I suggest actually just storing an integer instead of a formatted string - it will probably be easier for you in the long term.

If you want to write an integer value based on the database server's sense of time, you would do this instead, using [ServerValue.TIMESTAMP](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.ServerValue#timestamp), which gets an actual integer value as soon as the write hits the server:

```
      date: firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
```

If you were actually just hoping to get a server timestamp from Firestore's Timestamp API, that's not possible, because the server timestamp can only be calculated on the server.  The error is telling you that there is no `toDate()` method available on the [FieldValue](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.FieldValue) type object returned by [FieldValue.serverTimestamp()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.FieldValue#servertimestamp).  It doesn't return a [Timestamp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp).  It returns a token that you can provide to Firestore that interprets the timestamp on the server and not in the client app.  You should provide this token directly to Firestore if you want the server's timestamp in that field: