# date created in firebase functions is different from the date created in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

When a date object is created and set into firestore document using below

Firebase function:

```
var updateData = {status: 'closed', closedOn: new Date()}; 
    db_fs.collection("bookings").doc(bookingDocId).update(updateData).then(async () => {console.log("Document successfully updated!");});
```

then it goes into firebase like below

[image]

But if I set the date in the request (i.e. angular) instead of setting date inside firebase functions

Angular:

```
var updateData = {status: 'closed', createdOn:  firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date())};
```

Firebase function:

```
const data = req.body;
var updateData = data.updateData;  
db_fs.collection("bookings").doc(bookingDocId).update(updateData).then(async () => {console.log("Document successfully updated!");});
```

then it goes like below

[image]

So is there a way in angular/javascript to set the date such that it comes into firebase like shown in the first pic?

Comment: Make sure the time on your client is the same as the time on the server.

Comment: I did not understand. Can you give sample reference

Comment: my question is not about the date value. I want the same date structure when date is set from angular

Comment: But Google reveals that more people are using firebase and javascript, so this might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34718668/firebase-timestamp-to-date-and-time

Comment: Looking at the code snippet with angular, you're using the Timestamp function from firestore[1] it returns seconds and nanoseconds, so that explains why it's looking that way. Have you tried just putting `new Date()`[2] on the `createdOn` field?


[1] https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp


[2] https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date