# How can I serverTimeStamp to Date?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
  const docRef = await addDoc(collection(db, "question"), {
    title: writingTitle,
    createdAt: serverTimestamp(),
  });
```

If you write servertimestamp() when you write, the console window says {seconds=123123123, nanosecond=!@!@}} like this.
How can I change this to Date on the web?

Comment: refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34718668/firebase-timestamp-to-date-and-time)

Answer (score 1):

To convert a Firestore timestamp to a date, call `toDate()` on it after reading the value from the database. For more on this, see the [reference docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.timestamp.md#timestamptodate).

There is no way to get the value before that/without reading it, as `serverTimestamp()` only generates a token value/sentinel that the database server recognizes as a signal to write the date/time.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I do it (with Typescript / React Native):

```
  const docRef = await addDoc(collection(db, "question"), {
    title: writingTitle,
    createdAt: serverTimestamp(),
  });
  const docSnapshot = await docRef.get();
  //Then get any data from the added object
  const timestamp = docSnapshot.data().createdAt
```